# How do i delete every text channel with an event?

Tags: discord.py

i have been trying to figure out how to delete every channel in an event for fun. Does anyone know how to do this, and if so, can you help me out?

Comment: Try to do this yourself and if you got some problems, come here again and we'll help ya out!

Comment: I did. I tried to delete channels through an event many times with a ctx command. I dont know how to do it.

Comment: You get  a channel object and simply `.delete`, what's difficult about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the guild object, then use a for loop  to iterate through each text channel in the guild and do channel.delete(). You'll find everything else that you need in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference)

A  good practice is to familiarize yourself with the documentation so that later on you can find how to do this on your own, and you won't require help.